# Want to write to a file but I get the failure "Access to the path xy denied."

Tags: c#, stream, writefile

I am trying to write the data of a heartrate puls belt to a file.
Everytime I start the programm it says "Access to the path denied".

The file is not "read-only".
I also tried this from another question: File.SetAttributes(file, FileAttributes.Normal);

```
Debug.WriteLine(data[1]);
string path = @"C:\Users\...\DatenTest.txt";

using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
{
    var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
    writer.Write(data[1]);

}
return data[1];
```

Does anybody has an idea?

Comment: What is the actual path you are writing? There is a lot of stuff under "Users" that may or may not be available to non-elevated processes...

Comment: I just tried it with C:\Users\Documents\DatenTest.txt - didn't change anything :/

Comment: Is the file already locked by some other process? Does your application user have rights on the file?

Comment: No the file is not used by anything else. I'm using it with my admin profil so I guess yes..

Answer (score 0):

It's not the file you're being restricted from, it's the path (e.g. folder).  The three easy fixes are:

1) Adding "Everyone" permissions to the target folder's security tab in properties

2) Running your app in Administrator Mode

3) Switching to a folder without such stringent security (like "Documents")

Comment: I just tried it with C:\Users\Documents\DatenTest.txt - didn't change anything :/

Comment: That's not a valid windows path.  Did you mean C:\Users\\((username))\Documents\DatenTest.txt?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is, that the programm is in UWP.